# How to exclude a textfield from printing when its value is equal to zero in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a database where there are fields with values as zero.

[image]

I have jsp page where I will write the sql query and send the sql query as parameter to the JasperReports

invoicePDF.jsp

```
<%
Integer id = (Integer) session.getAttribute("id");
System.out.println("id is:"+id);
String sql=null;
Connection conn = null;
String termsOfPmnt = (String)session.getAttribute("termsOfPmnt");
String dispThrough = (String)session.getAttribute("dispThrough");
try 
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
    sql="select company_profile.companyName, and_so_on  from company_profile,invoice,invoiceclient_details where invoice.CId='"+id+"' and invoiceclient_details.CId='"+id+"'";  
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
    String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/report5.jrxml");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("sql",sql);
            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperReport, map, conn);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e) 
{e.printStackTrace();} 

        %>
```

and the jasper report code is as follows

```
        <detail>
    <band height="140" splitType="Prevent">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="13" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="24b49d3f-5c78-4a19-a4d2-e2cbff95a40d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{serial number}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="13" y="0" width="242" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="4332ae75-6371-4879-b805-9d07254f0784"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DescriptionOfGoods}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="0" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="54828e8d-bae0-4669-873e-36de8bf54446"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PerUnitPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="0" width="64" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e02408a1-2bcd-4fb9-94d3-ed0c0c1d8ff6"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nos]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="###0.00">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="459" y="0" width="96" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="00ba44d4-b287-4a29-8bf3-1ad07da760e8"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Quantity} *$F{PerUnitPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="255" y="0" width="54" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d74b9bd4-9608-44a7-b46e-55f39ed0c852"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="309" height="20" uuid="6e493a3e-c559-493b-ac86-314eb0df5a16"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="20" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="89f04225-eaba-4adc-a675-495d45ad27b2"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SubTotal:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="20" width="160" height="20" uuid="0e1bf36a-76f9-4644-a218-6c3bdcf2d1d1"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{subtotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="309" height="20" uuid="0a7f98e0-4db9-4ddc-a385-0e511193cb89"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="40" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="2f4cf4d5-51cd-435e-9279-c36e1bb578f0"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[VAT5.5:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="40" width="160" height="20" uuid="137c41e0-787d-4778-a9bf-1dd13d64fa3c"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vat5Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="309" height="20" uuid="70bd70aa-541d-424e-8dff-4febd8afbe32"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="60" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="929d9003-99cc-4f5d-b80f-8df5cb11af70"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[VAT14.5]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="60" width="160" height="20" uuid="7e8c8d41-2847-4a84-b068-22f40cd2e472"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{vat14Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="309" height="20" uuid="42d1448c-3e4e-4144-96c3-9d964c7296a9"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="80" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="ae220695-756d-48e3-b194-4e08baf43a46"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Service Tax:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="395" y="80" width="160" height="20" uuid="930d451c-232a-4bc9-9527-f8e207b023fc"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{svcTaxAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="309" height="20" uuid="63075a73-38d7-4954-951f-9f2169622ff8"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="100" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="002ff00b-29e6-44f1-bc9c-0b1e6d8c1504"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[CST:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="309" height="20" uuid="e440c11d-5996-48a4-95bf-d1eae7ba0291"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="309" y="120" width="86" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d7e3353f-4990-4299-a24f-9826f6265f84"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Grand Total]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="395" y="120" width="160" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9a1ac07c-8237-468f-bd1a-a6f5c4e6a1ee"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GrandTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <frame>
            <reportElement x="395" y="100" width="160" height="20" uuid="ae76daa8-a3de-4ba2-a258-7d67c5deb710">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{cstAmount}!=null && $F{cstAmount}.doubleValue()>0]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Now my question is when JasperReports's report is printing the values it should exclude the row in which the field is zero.

For Example:

I have vat5,vat14,servicetax and cst.If vat5 is zero and vat14,servicetax and cst are not zero then it should print vat14,servicetax and cst.Likewise if vat14 is zero and vat5,servicetax,cst are not zero then it should print vat5,servicetax,cst so that it exclude printing vat14 as zero in report

Comment: What do you mean exactly. 1) The fields shouldn't show `null`. 2) The fields should disappear when empty, leaving a blank space. 3) The fields should disappear and be ordered to the left, not following table headers.

Comment: @tobi6        The field should disappear when it is empty or its value is zero.And it should not a leave blank space while exporting to PDF,DOC or XLS.

Comment: @tobi6 For your clarity i have like vat5 and then vat14 and then servicetax and cst.If vat14 is zero then the lineup should be like vat5,servicetax and cst there should be no blank space in between.

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz `it should exclude the row in which the field is zero` - In your case you can use `printWhenExpression`. You can  the expression for the whole band (Detail)

Comment: @AlexK          I used printWhenExpression if you observe the code in detail band you can find a frame where i used it

Comment: @AlexK But its printing zero values

Comment: `<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{cstAmount} != null && $F{cstAmount} > 0.0]]></printWhenExpression>` - you can use this expression for Detail band (if you need to hide all content in it).

Comment: @AlexK I lost my hope and its not working really.Displaying always CST: 0.0 while exporting to PDF

Comment: Could you post the small *jrxml* to reproduce issue with *printWhenExpression* for *Detail* band. You can simplify the template, the only reproduce is required